How to restore MainWindow when the WPF app is running in Background Process
In my WPF app's App.xaml.cs, I have an override function to start up the app. When the app starts, first it'll check if there is another instance running. If so, the second instance will close. Then, it will check if the app was started automatically when the user's computer started. If it's opened automatically, it will hide the app by using MainWindow.Hide(). It then subscribes to the changes of the MainWindow. If there is any changes, the MainWindow will be displayed.
The purpose of my code is to hide the window when the computer starts. Then if user clicks on the exe icon, the window is displayed. Everything works fine, except when I click on the exe icon, I got error message "Another instance of the application is already running." while the app is actually running in the background process (I checked in Task Manager). Is there a way to restore the MainWindow when the user clicks on the exe?
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    const string mutexName = "YourAppMutexName";

    _mutex = new Mutex(true, mutexName, out bool isNewInstance);

    if (isNewInstance)
    {
        // Another instance of the application is already running
        MessageBox.Show("Another instance of the application is already running.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        Current.Shutdown();
    }
    else
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        bool startedAutomatically = IsStartedAutomatically(e.Args);


        NavigationStore navigationStore = new();

        navigationStore.CurrentVM = new LoginVM(navigationStore);

       
        if (startedAutomatically)
        {
            // The application was started automatically by Windows during startup
            // Do whatever you need to do in this case (e.g., hide the main window)
            MainWindow = new MainWindow()
            {
                DataContext = new MainWindowVM(navigationStore)
            };
            MainWindow.Hide();
            MessageBox.Show("App running but hidden because of auto startup");
            MainWindow.StateChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                if (MainWindow.WindowState == WindowState.Normal)
                {
                    MainWindow.Show();
                }
            };
        }
        else
        {
            // The application was started manually by the user
            // Do whatever you need to do in this case (e.g., show the main window)
            MainWindow = new MainWindow()
            {
                DataContext = new MainWindowVM(navigationStore)
            };
            MainWindow.Show();
            MessageBox.Show("App running...");
        }

        AddToStartup();
    }

  private bool IsStartedAutomatically(string[] args)
  {
      // Check if the "--startup" command-line argument is present
      return Array.Exists(args, arg => arg.Equals("--startup", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
  }


First off, you should configure your app for multiple instances. Then, in the startup, just scan the running processes. If you find a running instance, just take it to the foreground, and self kill the one was started latter.

@MarioVernari Do you have any code sample for my case? The thing is, the MainWindow is hidden, so could the method you mentioned show the MainWindow or it will act in a different direction?

If this is your solution to solve your other problem then be aware that this can be quite expensive as you are currently loading the complete WPF shell whereas the application window might never be shown. A Windows service is a very lightweight background application that in addition can be easily configured to be started automatically by the Windows OS (along with the other services). You would eliminate the hassle to run your application with arguments etc. You would instead register your service once and Windows will do the rest.

@BionicCode Yes I'm trying to solve the problem I posted before. The thing is I could not find any Window Service for a WPF app. I know what you mean by "expensive" but I might have to go with this if there is no other option.

"The thing is I could not find any Window Service for a WPF app" - A Windows service is a simple application. Like a console application. You communicate with from your wpf application or winforms application like you would do with any other server. It's a local server. You have to create that service on your own. Just choose the related application template in visual studio and start writing your code.Tutorial: Create a Windows service app.

If you are using. NET then creating a service has even become easier: Create Windows Service using BackgroundService.I recommend to try it. It's really easy. If you are afraid, then consider to create a second more lightweight console application that you keep running in the background. Now when the user starts the WPF application, the WPF application can close the console application and restart it when it itself is closing. The advantage of a service is that it is completely managed by Windows.

You can just use the synchronization primitive to synchronize both processes.
Let the first process wait for a signal triggered by the second process.
For security reasons I recommend using the EventWaitHandle instead of the Mutex.
Some remarks:

Calling Window.Hide on a window that was never shown before is pointless.
In addition, your conditions are wrong as you are shutting down your application when the Mutex is a new instance.
For security reasons, you should also avoid declaring the name of the synchronization object as const as this results in a global variable that will be visible outside your assembly for other processes.
Listening to the Window.StateChanged event is redundant as the window is not just not visible, it's never loaded. This means it is stateless. You have to show a Window before it can have a window state.
Referencing your App class using Application.Curent is also redundant when you are already inside the class scope. This doesn't hurt but it may look to some like you don't know exactly what you are doing.

An improved example of your code could look as follows:
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
  bool isProcessAlreadyRunning = EventWaitHandle.TryOpenExisting("YourAppMutexName", out EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle);
  if (!isProcessAlreadyRunning)
  {
    eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset, "YourAppMutexName");
    SecurityIdentifier? currentUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User;
    var accessRule = new EventWaitHandleAccessRule(currentUser, EventWaitHandleRights.Modify | EventWaitHandleRights.Synchronize, AccessControlType.Allow);
    var eventSecurity = new EventWaitHandleSecurity();
    eventSecurity.AddAccessRule(accessRule);
    eventWaitHandle.SetAccessControl(eventSecurity);

    var mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    MessageBox.Show("App running but hidden because of auto startup");

    // TODO::Do some initialization and/or start a background thread 
    // (that is active while the main thread is in a wait state). 
    
    // And when you are done wait for the signal of the other process
    eventWaitHandle.WaitOne();

    // We were finally signalled and can now continue to show the application window
    mainWindow.Show();
  }
  else // Another process of this application is already running
  {
    MessageBox.Show("Another instance of the application is already running.", "Error", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

    // Signal the other waiting process and allow it to proceed
    eventWaitHandle.Set();
 
    // End the current process
    Shutdown();

    return;
  }
}

